# Generating random sequence with minimum distance between elements (Matlab)

Tags: matlab

I need to generate a sequence of random numbers of a given length, on a given interval, with the constraint that no two numbers should be within a certain distance of each other. The interval on which the numbers are generated would be larger than the length of the sequence multipied by the minimum distance, but not by much, so some numbers would likely fail the condition.

It might be trivial, but I can't really think of a good solution to this problem, other than generating the random sequence, then iterating through it to check if each pair meets the condition, and if not, replace them and check again. It seems way too long, since there is no guarantee that the newly generated number would meet the condition, and the iteration itself could take quite some time.

Can anyone think of a better solution?

Comment: How important is it that the numbers could lie anywhere on the interval? You could generate random integers and multiply them by the minimum distance.

Comment: There may be ways of generating these values which doesn't sample evenly from all possible distributions that meet the constraints. Would that be acceptable? In addition, can you be clear whether you are generating integers or reals (presumably approximated by double precision) or some other number type?

Comment: Is there some constraint on what distribution the numbers come from?

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you could tell us what you need these numbers for.

Comment: If your interval is larger than the length x minimum distance, but "not by much", then it's not going to be really random, is it?

Comment: @A.Donda The numbers generated would serve as timepoints at which a certain event occurs in a test signal

Comment: @NeilSlater I would have to generate integers. Using random() with distribution type 'Uniform' while generates reals, is close to what I'm looking for, it is what I thought of using in case I find no better solution than  what's in the second paragraph

Comment: Peres, ok, so there's a natural sequence. Apart from being larger than a minimum threshold, do you have any other ideas about how the time-point-differences should be distributed? A standard choice would be exponential, I guess.

Comment: @A.Donda Exponential should be fine, the only thing that really matters about the sequence is to have the threshold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of possible answers, depending on how picky you are. If you're not to picky, this would work

```
L=10;  %length of interval
d=1;   %minimum distance
N=9;   %number of points
E=L-(N-1)*d;  %excess space for points

%generate N+1 random values; 
Ro=rand(N+1,1);     %random vector
%normalize so that the extra space is consumed
% extra value is the amount of extra space "unused"
Rn=E*Ro(1:N)/sum(Ro); %normalize

%spacing of points
S=d*ones(N,1)+Rn;  

%location of points, adjusted to "start" at 0
P=cumsum(S)-1
```

A typical sequence is

```
P =[
   0.060612
   1.4073
   2.676
   3.7901
   4.9476
   6.0333
   7.2426
   8.5684
   9.9247];
```

Comment: Just a small correction, at the last line distance shoulud be extracted to "start" at 0.

Answer (score 0):

Parameters taken from the other answer

```
L=10;  %length of interval
d=1;   %minimum distance
N=9;   %number of points
E=L-(N-1)*d;  %excess space for points
```

Now imagine you already have a solution `P`. If you now subtract `[0:d:(N-1)*d].'` you end up with N random numbers between 0 and E:

```
P-[0:d:(N-1)*d].'

ans =

    0.0606
    0.4073
    0.6760
    0.7901
    0.9476
    1.0333
    1.2426
    1.5684
    1.9247
```

That is something we can easily generate. Then add back what we previously subtracted:

```
>> sort(rand(1,N)*E).'+[0:d:(N-1)*d].'

ans =

    0.0689
    1.3737
    2.6342
    3.7631
    4.8775
    6.3897
    7.5310
    8.5904
    9.9004
```